# radio button selection to be done in order

Tags: javascript, arrays, radio-button

I have 4 fields,3 radio button and 1 question with its serial number in one line .i want if user clicks on answer of any question out of order, he should be alerted to answer next question no. first,Suppose after answering question 1 and 2 he answers 7 question radio button,alert message should popup forcing him to answer 3 question first, also i want to save the values of radio button in database,i have 12 question in one page,and total of 180 questions are there.

```
<tr><td>L<input type="radio" value="L"></td> 
        <td>?<input type="radio" value="?"></td>
        <td>D<input type="radio" value="D"></td>
       <td id="1">1. Question here</td> 
    </tr>
   <tr><td>L<input type="radio" value="L"></td> 
        <td>?<input type="radio" value="?"></td>
        <td>D<input type="radio" value="D"></td>
       <td id="2">2. question Here </td> 
    </tr><tr><td>L<input type="radio" value="L"></td> 
        <td>?<input type="radio" value="?"></td>
        <td>D<input type="radio" value="D"></td>
       <td id="3">3.  Question here</td> 
    </tr><tr><td>L<input type="radio" value="L"></td> 
        <td>?<input type="radio" value="?"></td>
        <td>D<input type="radio" value="D"></td>
       <td id="4">4. Question here</td> 
    </tr><tr><td>L<input type="radio" value="L"></td> 
        <td>?<input type="radio" value="?"></td>
        <td>D<input type="radio" value="D"></td>
       <td id="5">5. Question here</td> 
    </tr><tr><td>L<input type="radio" value="L"></td> 
        <td>?<input type="radio" value="?"></td>
        <td>D<input type="radio" value="D"></td>
```

Comment: Please, use the help of `{}` tool bar button to paste your code parts.

Comment: this is the project which i need to complete to get a job

Comment: Hey, why not get a real username on SO, and enter the stackoverflow careers? (:

Comment: ya will do it i have just created my account

Comment: ok so you wanted to do this with stackoverflow members help and always expect help from stackoverflow, well my suggestion is try to do it its not a big deal if you really didn't get what you want then post here.

Comment: this is d small part of it,where m stuck.i was doing it all alone until i was stuck.this is d part where m not able to get through

Answer (score 0):

You could always use javascript to enable radio buttons in order.
In that case, you render the radiobuttons disabled when the page is initially loaded. When a user clicks a radiobutton for question one, this triggers an event to enable the radiobuttons for question two etc.
If you name your radiobuttons consistently, you could jQuery to do this efficiently e.g. if you give them names like "q_1", "q_2", ...

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  var q = name.split("_");
  var next = "q_" + (parseInt(q[1]) + 1);
  $("input[name=" + next + "]").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: i m beginner in programing,so dont kno Jquery and kno basic of javascript and jsp.the code u have written m not able to understand it,how to use it.i kno simple programing only, bear with me,can u tell how to make radio button in order using javascript

Comment: First try to understand the code by yourself and if you don't understand something, please specify exactly what you don't understand. W3Schools and the jQuery documentation provide a pretty good source of information and should help you understand what's happening here. This should help to solve the entire exercise on your own.